# How to add data gathered by a click event, into a form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database, forms

I want to create a function that when the user clicks a item on the screen, say "apples", the text "apples" goes into the input form named "item" below, so they can update the items cost if they want to.

I have managed so far to get the text when you click on a item, but I have not managed to get the text to be rendered on the form itself. How do I go about doing this?

The list of food items on the screenshot is generated through PHP query, and creating individual tables.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.item').one('click', function(e){
        var txt = $(e.target).text();
        var form = document.forms['item'];
        $(form).append(txt);
        console.log(form);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="itemListContainer"> 
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT quanity, package, item, cost, store 
            FROM ingredients
            ORDER BY item, store ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo  "<table class='headertable'>
                    <tr class='tableheader'>
                        <th class='quanity cell'>Quanity</th>
                        <th class='package cell'>Packages</th>
                        <th class='item cell'>Item</th>
                        <th class='cost cell'>Cost</th>
                        <th class='store cell'>Store</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>";
        while($col = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo  "<table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='quanity cell'>$col[quanity]</td>
                            <td class='package cell'>$col[package]</td>
                            <td class='item cell'>$col[item]</td>
                            <td class='cost cell'>$col[cost] &euro;</td>
                            <td class='store cell'>$col[store]</td>
                        </tr>
                </table>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "no results";
    }
    ?>
</div>

<form id="addingredientsform" action="index.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="quanity" size="6" placeholder="Quanity">
 <input type="text" name="package" size="6" placeholder="Packages">
 <input type="text" name="item" size="25" placeholder="Item">
 <input type="text" name="cost" size="5" placeholder="Cost">
 <select name="store" placeholder="Store">
  <option value="Lidl" selected>Lidl</option>
  <option value="S-Mart">S-Mart</option>
  <option value="K-Mart">K-Mart</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Ingredient">
 <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Ingredient">
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Show us your HTML code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/DTcHh/38677/)**.

Since you're using jQuery and the `item` element is an `input` you should use `.val()` to set/get the value instead of `.text()`, like :

```
$('.item').on('click', function(e){
    var txt  = $(this).text();
    var form = $("input[name='item']");

    form.val( txt );

    console.log( form.val() );
});
```

**NOTE :** `one()` event will work just for the first click, use `on()` instead so you could click on the item you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is forms treated like arrays? I wouldn't of think to put input [ ] when trying to find my element. This worked, thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

On of the way to solve this problem to use val function for input

```
$('.item').on('click', function(e){
    var txt = $(e.target).text();
    var $form = $("input[name='item']");

    form.val(txt);
    console.log(form);
});
```